# USB port peripherals behaving strangely (Drivers)

Tags: windows-7, drivers, motherboard

Update: I fully believe this to be a driver issue at this point. I'm open to any suggestions as I've already wiped my driver and reinstalled windows so no risk of loosinf anything.

I recently installed a new motherboard/CPU and RAM on my computer. Ran through all the typical upgrade issues and finally got it booted up.

I am typing this from the computer, and everything works "okay", the main issue is that my mouse jumps around and pulls against me when I try and move it too fast. Keyboard works perfectly (but I notice audio interruptions when I type while audio is playing)

Things I have tried so far:

- Mouse is being detected as a serial mouse, so set start value on hkey/currentmachine/.../servmouse to 4
- Tried to reinstall drivers of all different kinds, still a couple that are not being detected (possible solution)
- Reseated all power connections on the motherboard
- Ensured the PSU has enough output for the new setup (It's 650W)
- Played around with tons of software settings (Razer Synapse won't even launch or detect anything Razer is connected)

The main thing that first led me to believe it was a power issue, was when I attempted to plug in an external harddrive to load a bios driver onto it and not a single port would even power it enough to be detected (the light would come on, but no detection)

Things to Note:

- Asus Maximus 8 Hero MB
- All Razer Peripherals (minus speakers, which initially were not working but I got to work eventually)
- The motherboard is seated slightly off kilter, most noticeable as you approach the bottom, but I don't see how that would cause this
- The voltage readings on the BIOS show as equal (5v = 5v, 12v = 12v, but I am unsure what these values mean or if this is significant in anyway)
  I feel like this image may be useful, these are the devices that are detecting in device manager but failing to install/find drivers for.

Any other pertenent information that is needed, let me know.

[image]

Comment: For the driver part, I recommend Snappy Driver Installer (https://sdi-tool.org/), which is pretty straightforward to use, and will download and install the proper drivers for you (if you need more info on how to use it, holler). For the power part, I'm not sure that's what's happening here, but you can find more here (https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?110272-What-do-5v-and-12v-RGB-cables-look-like-you-ask) on how to differentiate them and what kind of traps to avoid so as not to cook your mobo. Your mouse and external HDD could be driver-related, more than anything else. Update them.

Comment: @Didier Thanks, 2.5 Gb's of drivers installing now. Here's hoping, honestly this is the easiest solution so I'd be ecstatic if it was the fix. Really worried I'm going to have to go back to my old stuff to troubleshoot fully, such a pain

Comment: The driver software has successfully bricked both my mouse and keyboard and all other USB peripherals. Now what?

Comment: It created a backup but not really sure how to access that without a mouse or keyboard in the OS. SSomething I can do from boot menu or bios?

Comment: Something doesn't make sense. I luckily had a second computer to put the harddrive in and perform a system restore on. Put the harddrive back into the first computer and the keyboard and mouse stilll don't work.

Comment: Updating drivers can't brick a peripheral such as mouse and keyboard. They stop functioning, but they aren't bricked per se. Among the drivers you updated, was there one or more related to USB buses? In Snappy Driver, you can check boxes in the left pane to show you older but better drivers, or generic drivers. Check those boxes and see if SDI (Snappy Driver Installer) has more to offer than it already did. If your issues are power-related as you think, testing the charger/power supply would be worth a try too.

Comment: No USB connectivity on the computer at all now. I hear a click (real life physical click from the machine)when it goes from Windows loading to the login screen and the mouse and keyboard disable. The lights on the mouse are off but the lights on the keyboard are still on (no numlock test though all the keys do nothing once the OS starts) Do drivers not install the the harddrive? Are they on the motherboard somehow? I can put new bios drivers on a data drive and plug it in internally

Comment: Drivers are installed on the hard drive, in the OS (Windows in your case). On the motherboard, there's a collective firmware to start the whole thing, and a collection of individual firmwares, one per peripheral or group of peripherals (controllers, buses), so no, your mouse hasn't died, nor has your keyboard, they're just not recognized by Windows anymore. One sure way to find out: try to get in your BIOS with your USB keyboard by pressing whatever key combination is required to pause system start and check your BIOS. There's probably a USB setting set to "Off" instead of "On" or "Auto" there

Comment: ADDENDUM: in your case, getting into BIOS/UEFI should be via the F2 or Delete key. Press each one repeatedly during startup, as soon as the PC brand appears on-screen, until you are inside the BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: Using a driver installer is asking for trouble. The Windows drivers should in most cases be enough - if using Windows 10. Windows 7, dating from 11 years ago, will lack support for newer hardware. My advice is to install Windows 10, also because Windows 7 is a very big security risk, and this will solve your problems. Otherwise, download drivers for non-functioning devices from manufacturer websites yourself, wherever Windows 7 drivers are available (if not available then forget about this device).

Comment: To find out if the issue is software or hardware related, I would also recommend to boot the computer from a bootable linux system (either from CD or a thumb drive). Unless you have super weirdly specific hardware, Linux should support at least basic functionality for all your peripherals. If they work under Linux, the issue is likely OS/driver related. If they do not, it's likely hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Using a driver installer is asking for trouble, better to avoid them.

If you were using Windows 10, the Windows drivers should in most cases be enough.

However, you are using Windows 7 which dates from 11 years ago and
will therefore lack support for newer hardware.
As Microsoft has dropped support for Windows 7, many manufacturers no longer
supply drivers for it.

My advice is to install Windows 10.
This will most likely solve your problems of drivers, but also because
running Windows 7 is a very big security risk with all its well-known
security vulnerabilities.

If you prefer Windows 7, download drivers for non-functioning devices manually
only from the manufacturer website. 
If Windows 7 drivers are not available, try drivers for very similar models.
If nothing is available from the manufacturer, then this device is a lost cause.

Answer (score 0):

So a couple of questions to start with and I apologize if you already answered them elsewhere in this thread but I find I work through technical problems best when I feel I can tick each potential box off to narrow the problem down.

1. What is the specific mouse and keyboard? I saw Razer listed but the specific models are important because their could be known hardware or drivers issues. Usually its best to use the latest drivers for your hardware, but occasionally like all software the most recent version may have inadvertently introduced a bug that was never patched by the developer especially since Windows 7 was reaching its end of life support, and therefore using an older version of the drivers might fix the problem.
2. Does the mouse and keyboard display the same behavior on other PCs?
3. Have you used another USB mouse and keyboard on the PC and if so does it result in the same behavior? If it does, do you have a ps/2 mouse and a p2/2 port? If you do you can see if its exclusively a USB problem.
4. Have you checked your BIO's USB setting?
5. You used Snappydriver to install your drivers and as someone has already said thats not really the best way to do it, instead you always want to install your drivers through windows update or through the manufacturers website. Are the drivers installed by Snappydriver still installed on your OS?
6. You mentioned you thought it might be a power problem. Do you have a spare PSU? If not do you have any non-essential parts like a CD Drive, secondary HDD or SSD, or Graphics card that you can remove to boot up the computer and allow more wattage to be available?
7. Have you tried booting from a linux USB or CD on the computer like Johannes suggested? If so are you having the same problems as in windows?